# cmake - two targets that depends on single static library that should be compiled based on the target that is being built

Tags: cmake

I have a static library and two target executables, let's call them **libA**, **EXE1**, **EXE2**.

**libA** has pre-processor macros which needs to be enabled or disabled and another static library which needs to be linked or ignored based on the target executable that I am building.

Let's say, if I am building EXE1. Then I need to enable the macros in libA and link another static library to it.

If I am building EXE2, I need to disabled the macros in libA and don't link to another library.

I am confused on how to solve this issue. Please kindly help in solving this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of an interface library as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(test)

add_library(libA INTERFACE)
target_sources(libA INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/liba.c)

add_executable(exe1 exe1.c)
target_link_libraries(exe1 libA)
target_compile_definitions(exe1 PUBLIC -DENABLE_THE_MACROS)

add_executable(exe2 exe2.c)
target_link_libraries(exe2 libA libOtherStatic)
target_compile_definitions(exe1 PUBLIC -DDISABLE_THE_MACROS)
```

`libA` is a "virtual" target that does not produce any output, but it can be linked to other targets (here `exe1` and `exe2`)
Any target that links to `libA` will automatically receive the sources of `libA` as well. Note that I had to make the path absolute to prevent a warning.

Comment: @cpp_enthusiast If an answer helps you, please [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) so other people know it works and can make use of it later.